# What is the minimum time steps for training hidden markov model?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I'm working with hidden markov model.
And I wonder what is the minimum time steps for training hidden markov model.
For example, I have weight data with 3 years of 100 people like following

```
      2018 2019 2020 
id1    70   73   75
id2    73   70   68
...
id100  68   63   62
```

One hidden markov model like HMM1 can train weight data of id1 person which shows the increasing weight pattern?

Comment: You probably don’t want an HMM for this.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Please explain the reason? According to the lectures that I took, HMM looked fit for this data. And if HMM doesn't fit to this data, what kind of method can be better?

Comment: Welcome to CV. It seems that you have provided very little information to draw an answer from. Please put everything in the question that you would consider as needed, if someone asked you this question.